# Cosmos DB failover read location when not specified

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-sdk-.net

Let's say I have a Cosmos DB set up in three regions A, B, and C, where A is the write region. Also I have Automatic Failover turned *off*.

When using the .NET SDK in a client, if I set `ConnectionPolicy.EnableEndpointDiscovery = true` but *don't* specify anything for the `ConnectionPolicy.PreferredLocations` property, what will happen to reads (and writes), from the client, if region A has an outage?

Also, suppose I do specify `ConnectionPolicy.PreferredLocations = {A, B}` and both those regions have outages, what happens then?

I can't find any [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.connectionpolicy.preferredlocations?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_ConnectionPolicy_PreferredLocations) that describes and explains the outcome of these [scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/regional-failover).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If have `EnableEndpointDiscovery` enabled, writes will get automatically routed to the new primary region (if not, they will fail during a primary region failure). If you  have `PreferredLocations`, reads will get routed to the regions in order of preferrence. If this is not specified, then reads will fail when the primary is unavailable. In other words, you must enable both to have high availability in case of a regional failure.

If you have `PreferredLocations = {A, B}` and both regions fail, then reads will be unavailable till the services are brought back online. Generally, this scenario is very unlikely as it involves multiple regions failing simultaneously.

Some additional details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/regional-failover